# django modify request parameters in templates

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

So I wrote an app that returns an the query results. Let's assume the query URL is `/query/?A=a&B=b`

And now I want to add a "sort by" button to my results page to allow the users to sort the results by time, or type. Essentially just allow user to visit `/query/?A=a&B=b&sorted=time` or `/query/?A=a&B=b&sorted=type`

The easiest way is to append `sorted=` after the current URL. For example `<a href = "{{ request.get_full_path }}&sorted=time">` But the problem is that if user first sorts by time, then sorts by type, you will have `/query/?A=a&B=b&sorted=type&sorted=time`

I suppose I can do some fancy string operations, but I don't know if I can do that in django template language, and I suppose there is a better way of doing it. There should be somewhere I can just modify the GET request and let the page refresh.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [django-tables2's solution](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/templatetags/django_tables2.py#L125) (you might just want to look at django-tables2 in general if you're displaying this data in a table).

Answer (score 0):

Two `GET` variables with the same name is ambigious. You can define different varaibles for the different types of sorting. Sorting has two options either ascending or descending depending on the context, you also need those values so that user can go back to the default sorting.

```
/query/?A=a&B=b&sort_type=asc&sort_time=desc
```

Then in view:

```
sort_type = request.GET.get('sort_type', '')
sort_time = request.GET.get('sort_time', '')

qs = MyModel.objects.all()

if sort_type:
    if sort_type == 'asc':
        qs = qs.order_by('type')
    elif sort_type == 'desc':
        qs = qs.order_by('-type')

# same goes with sort_time
# ...
# pass sort_type and sort_type or all get variables in the context to generate url in template
```

Now in template:

```
<a href = "{{ request.get_full_path }}?&sort_time={{sort_time}}&sort_type={{sort_type}}">
```